# ActiveRecord - Querying association with multiple condition pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here's some context with a small Database Schema

```
Order
  -> id
LineItem
  -> id
  -> order_id
Transaction
  -> id
  -> transaction_type
  -> successful
  -> line_item_id
```

Basically, what we're trying to do is **fetch all orders that have multiple transactions, matching specific conditions pairs on transactions**

Here's a very basic table schema to use as an example:

```
Order (orders)
+----+
| id | 
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 | <--
|  3 |

Line Items (line_items)
+---------------+
| id | order_id |
|----|----------|
| 1  | 1        |
| 2  | 2        | <--
| 3  | 3        |

Transactions (transactions)
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | transaction_type | successful | line_item_id |
|----|------------------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 2                | 1          | 1            |
| 2  | 2                | 0          | 2            | <--
| 3  | 1                | 1          | 1            |
| 4  | 3                | 1          | 2            | <--
| 5  | 1                | 1          | 3            |
| 6  | 3                | 1          | 3            |
```

I have highlighted with arrows the records we will focus on.

The `Order` class to put more in context:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :transactions, through: :line_items
end
```

As I said, we want to fetch all orders through specific constraints (pairs) on `transactions`.

So we'd only like to select one `order` if we have `(At least ONE transaction with "transaction_type" = 2 AND "successful = 0"), AND (At least ONE transaction with "transaction_type" = 3 AND "successful" = 1)`

This **cannot** be a `OR`. The order should only be selected if the two constraint pairs are respected.

(Example: I want only orders, that have line items that ONLY have ONE transaction of type 2 AND are unsuccessful). [This should only give me orders that have line items with a single type of that transaction, although it can have any other type of transactions]

I've been searching the last 10 hours how to achieve this, to no avail, and so I turn to you for answers. **In case you are curious: We use postgres**.

I don't even know where to start for the query, and even less for the ActiveRecord syntax.

Good example of the problem:
https://github.com/dsounded/ransack_example/blob/master/app/services/finder.rb#L7
The issue with this is the inability to order or paginate the result.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to join Transactions with itself

```
Transactions.joins("INNER JOIN transactions as x ON x.line_item_id=transactions.line_item_id").where("transactions.transaction_type=2 AND transactions.successful=0").where("x.transaction_type=3 AND x.successful=1").includes(:order)
```

Comment: Such query results in `nil`: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN transactions as x ON x.line_item_id=transactions.line_item_id WHERE (transactions.transaction_type=2 AND transactions.successful='f') AND (x.transaction_type=3 AND x.successful='t')`

Comment: what is the type of successful field in the database ??

Comment: It's boolean. 'f' || 't'

Comment: I did. Look at the comment. I'm using 'f' and 't'

Comment: actually i tried to insert the sample data you wrote in the question then run this query on it and it show results normally

Comment: I will try to rewrite it for the "Order" model instead of Transaction model, since it's the orders we want to fetch.

Comment: could you divide the query and see if there is any valid result in the database ??   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "transactions" WHERE (transactions.transaction_type=2 AND transactions.successful='f') then apply for the second case

Comment: Part 1: count: 847
Part 2: count: 4169

Comment: and what about join only without conditions `SELECT * FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN transactions as x ON x.line_item_id=transactions.line_item_id` and track the results to see if the case you search for is already exist in the database ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join with a `having` and a `where`, something like:

```
    Order.joins(line_items: :transactions).select("orders.*")
.group("orders.id").having(count(transactions.id) > 2).where(your conditions)
```

Comment: `Order.joins(line_items: :transactions).select("orders.*").group("orders.id").having('count(transactions.id) > 2').where("(transactions.transaction_type = 2 AND transactions.successful = 'f') OR (transactions.transaction_type = 3 AND transactions.successful = 't')")` will yield a lot of results, since some orders can have multiple line items with each a transaction of the same type & success. As such it will not yield correct results.

Comment: The query still yields wrong results as I depicted above.